# HTTP Status 500 - Component ID main:j_idt56 has already been found in the view

Tags: tomcat

We are migrating the application from IBM WAS8.5.2 to Tomcat 7. We have used javax.faces-2.1.7 to compile and run the JSF pages in the current project. The issue related to the state saving in session scope. The dynamic ID which generating and append to the form id is not refreshing by which causing the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID main:j_idt56 has already been found in the view.  
com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:836)
com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:820)
com.sun.faces.util.Util.checkIdUniqueness(Util.java:820)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.saveView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:461)
com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:89)
com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
```

In order to resolve this we have commented the checkIdUniqueness call from the saveView method in the class `com.sun.faces.application.view.StateMangementStrategyImpl.java inside the javax.faces-2.1.7.jar`.

Is the above workaround solution the right approach? Point to note here is that we cannot change the `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` to client and also `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING` to false because in our application traversing between pages is using session scope, tried with both options and other application functionality gets affected. Is this is correct way of doing?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.